# Dynamic ScrollTo function requires next element

Tags: javascript, dynamic, css-selectors, parent-child

I have multiple rows on my website and a scrollto() button, which is always at the bottom of the screen.

Depending on where the user is located on my site at a certain moment, I would like them to move to the next row after they clicked the button.

I am aware of how to make a user scrollto(), but I have no clue what kind of selector I should use.

```js
function myFunction() { 
var winScroll = window.scrollTop; // current scroll of window
// find closest div
var rows =  document.querySelectorAll('.row');
var closest = rows[0]; // first section
var closest_idx = 0;
var min = closest.offsetTop - winScroll;
rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
    var divTopSpace = row.offsetTop - winScroll;
    if( divTopSpace < min && divTopSpace > 0 ) {
        closest = row;
        closest_idx = index;
        min = divTopSpace;
    } 
});
var next_idx = closest_idx + 1;
if (next_idx == rows.length) {
    next_idx = 0;
}
console.log(rows[next_idx]);
}
```

```css
.rowOne {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
}

.rowTwo {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: firebrick;
}

.rowThree {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.btn {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="row rowOne">
    <div class="a">
      <div class="b">
        Foo
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row rowTwo">
    <div class="a">
      <div class="b">
        Bar
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="row rowThree">
    <div class="a">
      <div class="b">
        Foobar
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="btn" class="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Button</button>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are all the same height (100% of the window height), the simple solution would be to simply scroll by that amount.

```
window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight);
```

Otherwise, you'll need to detect which element is the "current" one, and then get it's next sibling, and then scroll to it.  Something like this (haven't tested, so syntax might be off, but this should give you an idea)

```
var winScroll = window.scrollTop; // current scroll of window
// find closest div
var rows =  document.querySelectorAll('.row');
var closest = rows[0]; // first section
var closest_idx = 0;
var min = closest.offsetTop - winScroll;
rows.forEach(function(row, index) {
    var divTopSpace = row.offsetTop - winScroll;
    if( divTopSpave < min && divTopSpave > 0 ) {
        closest = row;
        closest_idx = index;
        min = divTopSpace;
    } 
});
var next_idx = closest_idx + 1;
if (next_idx == rows.length) {
    next_idx = 0;
}
window.scrollTo(rows[next_idx].scrollTop);
```

Comment: Thank you, 
I will try to figure out how to make it work.
I pasted your code in my example but something seems to be wrong.
Is it possible for you to have a glimpse?

Comment: if you make a jsfiddle I can play around with it to make it work

Comment: Thanks, almost perfect.
The thing is though. It works good, when you are in the middle between rowOne and rowTwo, because the window scrollsTo rowTwo. But when you are between rowTwo and rowThree the window scrolls back to rowTwo, instead of rowThree. Do you have an explanation for that behavior?

Comment: Hey Dave, Could you have another look please?